# Is there any underlying theory on how limit evaluation tricks work?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I was reading the paper, "Integration in finite terms" by Maxwell Rosenlicht, and in the last page the author mentions that G.H Hardy has a book on how integration of functions in elementary calculus does comprise a coherent system and that it is not a form of "art" as many people believe.

After reading that I was wondering whether the way limit problems are solved in elementary calculus have any kind of systematic basis. Do we adopt the techniques to solve limit problems ( like multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate) because they "work" or is there some underlying idea that we used to derive these techniques ?

Link to Rosenlicht's paper : http://www.dm.unipi.it/pages/gianni/public_html/Alg-Comp/rosenlicht.pdf

Comment: I suppose the analogous thing to $\int e^{x^2} dx$ would be an elementary function with a limit that exists but is unknown.

Comment: In mathematics, there are no tricks. There are methods (or techniques, as you call them). Only those who don't understand them call them "tricks"."

Comment: Very true @ProfessorVector. However sometimes (in my case mostly) it is the fault of instructors and textbooks alike when they fail to explain why some technique works. For example when one learns the method of long division to get square roots (say at age 13 years) no one explains why that strange method works.

Comment: I'm afraid your example is a bit unfortunate: almost nobody understands how (or why) long division *for the sake of division* works, and they don't have to. You don't have to know Maxwells's equations to switch on the lights. That method for square roots isn't taught in the schools of my country, not in the last 100 years or so. Nowadays, there are calculators. *But* you should know *what* they calculate (not necessarily *how*, they don't use the method you mention for calculating square roots, I suspect).

Comment: @ProfessorVector: wolfram can evaluate integrals so there is no need to learn techniques of integration or how they work? I disagree. On the other hand everyone seems to explain how calculators evaluate square roots. So it's more the whim of the textbook author which decides what to explain and what not.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Besides square roots, no one explains at that time why the method of "carry" in addition works or why "borrow" works in subtraction. Even if they tried explaining that I think it will be very hard for the pupils to really understand. The distributive law is not very intuitive. So its not really a whim of the textbook author; its the fact that the author realizes the capacity of the students and tries to give them maximum benefit within their capacity.

Comment: @For the OP: Yes there is an underlying theory. You may pick up any decent real analysis book such as Analysis by Tao to learn it.

Comment: Avoiding unnecessary digression, the techniques for evaluation of limits are fairly standard and discussed in many books of calculus. The details of why those methods work might not be available in every book, but some do give such detail. You can also go through the [blog series](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-1.html) for a thorough discussion on this topic.

Comment: @Shahab: this very attitude ensures that students never try to understand how/why of anything and the culture of rote learning is established.

Comment: @Shahab I have read Rudin and I'm aware of how limits work just as I'm aware of how integrals work theoretically. This question isn't about that, it's about why we choose to use certain methods of evaluating limits over others when doing a particular problem. Just as it was mentioned in the paper linked above that there is a systematic way to evaluate integrals and it's not an "art", I was looking for something similar for limits in that vein.